# How can I write a custom query in Active Directory Exlorer?

Tags: search, active-directory

I have downloaded Microsoft's Active Directory Explorer (AD Explorer).
I have connected successfully to Active Directory and I can search successfully users. 
I want to perform a custom search without using the panel provided. Do you know a way to do this? I tried building the search I want from the search panel but with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AD explorer doesn't offer this by the looks of it, however the standard 'Active Directory Users and Computers' snap-in does. Here's how:

1. Open Active Directory users and computers (dsa.msc)
2. Create new query under "Saved Queries"
3. Choose Define Query > Find "Custom Search" > Advanced Tab
4. Enter LDAP Query > Paste ADExplorer query string
5. Save query

(Inspired by https://forum.sysinternals.com/active-directory-explorer_topic22035.html)